# Who should create business objects?

Tags: c#, data-access-layer, domain-model

Since business/domain objects should be unaware of their persistence they obviously must not contain code that loads data from a database to initialize themselves.

On the other hand not all of the properties of business object have public setters to aid encapsulation and to avoid setting them to invalid values.

That means that no other class can fully initialize a business object, when it its data is fetched from a database.

Since all of the above are common best practices, there has to be some solution to that problem. **So who should be responsible of constructing business objects and filling them with data from the database?**

Note: The only option that comes to my mind is adding *all* the properties to the constructor, which would be highly impractical in my opinion.

Comment: Typically, you create business objects in the `Service` layer (i.e. `UserService` creates the `User` bean) then it should send that to a repository (i.e. `UserRepository`) to persist it. To find existing beans, call the service to call the repository - the repository creates the bean and populates it from the database

Comment: reading your comments I think your problem comes from your idea of what a business object 'should' be. It seems to me that you probably have classic OO style objects with business logic in their methods. Whereas Repositories come from a later era where that logic would be placed in a service and the object would only contain data

Comment: Its not impossible to mix these concepts, but for example how are you currently creating your objects?

Comment: @Ewan Anemic domain model is considered an antipattern. It is far from being "modern". And "repositories" are as old as object modeling.

Comment: @Ewan: I'm currently in the process of deciding how to create my objects based on best practices. Therefore I read a lot about what business objects 'should' look like. The problem is that there is no real agreement on this, but just a lot of different opinions...

Comment: @Euphoric: That's what I read. But I have never seen a fully functional example of an application that does not use one anti-pattern or another out of necessities like this...

Comment: @Karsten there are a lot of old fogeys who will try and push the Classic 'old timer' OO aproach on you, citing other 'grampas of programming' to make their point. But you shouldnt listen to them

Comment: besides, there's nothing wrong with having your 'all the properties' constructor. it works with repositories and keeps encapsulation. why dont you like it?

Comment: @Ewan: Some of the objects I am working with have a lot of properties. So I wanted to avoid repeating a lot of code to make it more maintainable. It just seems that I have to repeat the code *somewhere* so I might just do it in the constructor...

Comment: @Ewan Because there is conceptual difference between "new entity" and "existing entity, but created from repository". And using one point (eg. constructor) is not an ideal thing to do.

Comment: @Euphoric: Well I could just create two constructors for these cases.

Comment: @Euphoric true, how do you handle this issue?

Comment: I think you have a number of solutions Karsten, I use the ADM pattern, which doesn't have this problem, but as you see is considered 'bad' by some poeple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite few solutions to this problem. But neither of are "perfect".

1. Use reflection to set private fields or properties. Most ORMs use this solution. The problem might be when ORM sets property, that has some logic on it, leading to illogical state of the entity (I got burned by this quite a few times).
2. Abstract away "data persistence" as key/value map. This way, the entity can persist itself and is still independent of specific persistence technology. But you still need to explicitly code this.
3. Builder pattern. Have separate class with same properties, that can access the private fields of the entity, but is only used in construction. Major disadvantage is need to have builder for each entity.
4. Create a DTO, that mirrors the state of the entity, but not it's behavior. The entity can then read/create this DTO to load or persist itself. Same disadvantage as above.

I personally don't see any good answer to your question, unless you can manage to do one of the previous solutions automatically. Either by code generation or by having language support. For example, having language support for "builder pattern" would help a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "Abstract away data persistence as key/value map"?

Comment: @Karsten Its same as DTO, but instead of creating a class, you save it as Dictionary<string, object> where key is name of a property and object is a value.

Answer (score 0):

The repository should be able to create a business object from information provided by the datalayer. The logic is that since the repository should be persisting the object you passed in in a way which hides the implementation from the user it has to be able to serialize and deserialize that object without any extra info.

a common pattern if you have object with private data is to have the private information passed in via a constructor.

Creating new objects should be possible without calling a repository. Usually through a public constructor

eg:

```
public class Model {
        public String Id {get;set;}
        public String Colour { get; set; }

        public Model(String id, String colour)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Colour = colour;
        }
    }

    public interface IRepository
    {
        void Add(Model item);
        Model Get(string id);
    }

    public class RepositorySql : IRepository
    {
        private string constr;
        public RepositorySql(string connstr)
        {
            this.constr = connstr;

        }
        public void Add(Model item)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into table (userid,colour) values (@userid,@colour)", conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", item.Id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@colour", item.Colour);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }


        public Model Get(string id)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from table where id=@id)", conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", item.UserId);
                    SqlDataReader dr  =cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    if (dr.Read())
                    {
                        Model i = new Model(dr["id"].ToString(), dr["colour"].ToString());
                        return i;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: My problem is the other way round. How do your *fetch* objects with private or without setters?

Comment: sorry I was trying to keep the code minimal. updated

Comment: This basically means you would just add all the properties to the constructor?

Comment: personally I would add public setters, but since this is not in scope. yes the constructor should be able to construct the object

Answer (score -1):

This can get complicated due to terminology - there can often be several names for the same thing, or one pattern can be amalgamation of other discrete patterns. Hopefully this (very brief) answer will make sense to you.

You would normally have a data layer (DAL) or "data service" whose job it is to talk to the data store (alternatively it may talk to a repository layer or an ORM).

The layer responsible for creating the data entities ("business objects") could differ depending on your setup. An ORM (like Entity Framework) can return you data entities, but you'll typically want to change these to something more agnostic before they get into the rest of your application, so that would be the job of the DAL (or specific data "service") to map them from EF objects to regular data entities.

Alternatively the repository layer can create the entities as it is used to query the underlying data store.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know about the DAL, ORMs and so on. The problem is, that good business objects have read only properties and don't allow invalid states which will occur if you just set one property after another via an ORM. How do  you handle those cases?

Comment: I think you are confusing something there... there is no such thing as "good business objects having read only properties" - you will need to change the values of those properties at some stage, **these objects will be useless to you when using MVVM**. What you are thinking of is making the objects immutable, which is a different philosophy again.

Comment: I know there are a lot of different opinions about what *good* business objects look like and I am not talking about making *all* the properties read only. Just properties which are not supposed to be set directly (e.g. primary keys). I have made all properties public in the past to appease ORM, but I'm currently unhappy with this approach and looking for something more robust.

Comment: I'm not a fan of ORMs myself. One approach you can use is for the immutable (read only) properties to be passed in on the constructor, but this gets messy if you start passing too many values. There is no such thing as "more robust" - there are positives and negatives to each approach (that's why there are so many ways of doing this). Pick one way and stick with it until you find a reason why you really shouldn't use it.